What was the deaf girl, Regan, doing to the radio in this scene?
In A Quiet Place Part II (2021),  Regan (the deaf girl) is shown using a radio in this scene: 

Then she goes to the top, looks for a fire, and identifies it on the map:

And she takes a wristwatch out of the box:

In the next scene, Regan, along with her mother and Marcus
headed somewhere.
What was the deaf girl, Regan, doing to the radio in this scene?

Isn't she preparing an amplifier to blast the high-pitched noise that the aliens don't like?
